# Can the Samsung SL-M2835DW be configured to work with Windows 2000?

Tags: network-printer, windows-2000

I have a client using Windows 2000 and they'd like to get a networked SL-M2835DW working with their configuration. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes.

You can get it working easily. I was running Windows 2000 as a guest OS in VirtualBox. Here is the write up on how I did it on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226714/3285). I shared the CUPS printer with the host.

That said, I think you could start at `Step 4.2` and rather than installing a *Network Printer* go the local route. You can find the [PPD for Samsung M262x 282x Series here](https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=pxlmono-Samsung&printer=Samsung-M262x_282x&show=1). This works in Windows. It should be as simple as selecting it on a local install of the Adobe Universal PostScript Windows Driver.

Comment: Except that the SL-M2835DW does not support PostSCript. It supports PCL5e, PCL6 and SPL (a form of GSI printing)

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

[Samsung drivers](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SL-M2835DW/XAA) only seem to go as far back as XP for the SL-M2835DW. However, according to the [specs](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/printers/SL-M2835DW/XAA), the printer does support PCL5 so you should be able to pick any PCL5 driver and get it to work, as PCL5 is quite standard. About the main differences between different printers are the various options available, e.g. different trays, duplexer, etc. As this printer only has 1 tray (plus manual feed) you should have minimal problems. Try something like an HP laserjet 4.

To install it, use the Add Printer wizard. When asked for the printer model, select Laserjet 4 (or see if you can find a suitable Samsung in the list) If the printer is networked via its own network port, create a Standard TCP/IP port for it. If it is USB connected to another PC, tell the wizard you are using the parallel port (LPT1). When the installation is finished, change the port to the serving PC.